# How to bind all users in an Active Directory to a dropdown list on a SharePoint site?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, active-directory

I am trying to do what the topic describes and my code so far is:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://myDomain/DC=somecollege, DC=someState, DC=edu", myUser, myPassword);
DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Person))";

SearchResultCollection searchResult = directorySearcher.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult srUSers in searchResult)
{
    DirectoryEntry de = srUsers.GetDirectoryEntry();
    lbSiteOwnerGroups.Items.Addd(New ListItem(de.Name.ToString()));
}
```

With this code all persons gets bound to a drop down but the format is:
CN=lastName firstName
How do I get only the names and not "CN=", I assume I should not need to you string manipulation here.

If I try with de.Path.Tostring() it looks like:

```
<option value="LDAP://myDomain/CN=DOE John, OU=IT, OU=_someville_NonTeaching, OU=Staff_someville, DC=somecollege, DC=nsw, DC=edu,DC=au">LDAP://myDomain/CN=DOE John, OU=IT, OU=Staff_someville_NonTeaching, OU=Staff_someville, DC=somecollege, DC=fl, DC=edu,DC=com<option>
```

I have seen I can use de.Properties["mail"].ToString() for example but gives me the error "operator has returned an error". I haven't worked with AD before and I if I get in contact with the AD administrator what questions should I ask him if the questions I have here needs answewer from the actual admin?

Also, there is a subdomain or childdomain that's called Staff, how can I get users from this domain only?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a warning - the dropdown list will become unusable after you've reached a hundred staff or so, which is why the OOTB user picker doesn't use a drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be like the following code:

```
foreach (SearchResult srUsers in searchResult)
{
    DirectoryEntry de = srUsers.GetDirectoryEntry();
    lbSiteOwnerGroups.Items.Add(new ListItem(de.Properties["CN"].Value.ToString()));
}
```

***EDIT***

I didn't see the second part of the question.  If you want the users from child domain only, you can make your DirectorySearcher binded to the child domain.  So, instead of using

```
LDAP://myDomain/DC=somecollege, DC=someState, DC=edu
```

You should use something like this

```
LDAP://childdomain.myDomain/DC=childdomain,DC=somecollege, DC=someState, DC=edu
```

You need to find out the correct LDAP domain root path for your child domain.  I can post more information if you need help on this.

Comment: Hi Harvey, I tried with ["CN"].ToString() and not .Value.ToString() as you suggested which solved my first problem. I'll see if I can figure out how to get users from child domain only and come back with questions if it doesn't work.